# MacBook Pro 13" TouchBar 2017 won't sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, power, power-management

I have a really huge problem with my Brand new MacBook Pro 13".  When I close the lid and I open it after serveral hours the battery is completely empty. So the Mac obviously won't sleep and do working in the background.

So after that I checked the logs in the Console App and I found an process that will running every 1-2 minutes and obviously that will empty the MacBook battery.

This process is called **diagnosticd** and does the follwing on console in short:

```
Jul 21 09:49:20 Buzz diagnosticd[691]: Streaming server Reconnected
Jul 21 09:49:20 Buzz diagnosticd[691]: Cancelling the existing xpc
Jul 21 09:49:20 Buzz diagnosticd[691]: Disconnecting the client connection
Jul 21 09:49:20 Buzz diagnosticd[691]: Send_stream_Request, connecting to Streaming server
Jul 21 09:51:39 Buzz diagnosticd[691]: Streaming server Reconnected
Jul 21 09:51:39 Buzz diagnosticd[691]: Cancelling the existing xpc
Jul 21 09:51:39 Buzz diagnosticd[691]: Disconnecting the client connection
Jul 21 09:51:39 Buzz diagnosticd[691]: Send_stream_Request, connecting to Streaming server
Jul 21 09:52:52 Buzz diagnosticd[691]: Streaming server Reconnected
Jul 21 09:52:52 Buzz diagnosticd[691]: Cancelling the existing xpc
Jul 21 09:52:52 Buzz diagnosticd[691]: Disconnecting the client connection
Jul 21 09:52:52 Buzz diagnosticd[691]: Send_stream_Request, connecting to Streaming server
Jul 21 09:53:59 Buzz diagnosticd[691]: Streaming server Reconnected
Jul 21 09:53:59 Buzz diagnosticd[691]: Cancelling the existing xpc
Jul 21 09:53:59 Buzz diagnosticd[691]: Disconnecting the client connection
Jul 21 09:53:59 Buzz diagnosticd[691]: Send_stream_Request, connecting to Streaming server
Jul 21 09:55:14 Buzz diagnosticd[691]: Streaming server Reconnected
Jul 21 09:55:14 Buzz diagnosticd[691]: Cancelling the existing xpc
Jul 21 09:55:14 Buzz diagnosticd[691]: Disconnecting the client connection
Jul 21 09:55:14 Buzz diagnosticd[691]: Send_stream_Request, connecting to Streaming server
Jul 21 09:56:22 Buzz diagnosticd[691]: Streaming server Reconnected
Jul 21 09:56:22 Buzz diagnosticd[691]: Cancelling the existing xpc
Jul 21 09:56:22 Buzz diagnosticd[691]: Disconnecting the client connection
Jul 21 09:56:22 Buzz diagnosticd[691]: Send_stream_Request, connecting to Streaming server
```

That will only happen when I have an active Wi-Fi Connection and the lid is closed.
For me It looks like some process will keep the diagnosticd process alive and working. I reinstalled the MacBook 3 Times, nothing works.

Have anybody an idea how can I see more about diagnosticd and the process that will keep this deamon alife?

Had anybody else the Problems?

I really hope you can help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, Apple changed my brandnew MacBook Pro. The result, no more Problems

Comment: Sorry for writing a new answer but I think the only way to solve this problem is to change the complete hardware.

Comment: @pjctech the author is self-answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

If your power-nap setting is on for battery power, the computer may be connecting to your network and then dropping the connection, which would be an issue with your Wi-Fi network.